# Properties of classes

Tags: c#

I have two classes and a method like this:

```
public class Class1 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Class2 Params { get; set; }
}

public class Class2
{
    public string Param1 { get; set; }
    public string Param2 { get; set; }
    public string Param3 { get; set; }
}

private Class1 GetData(SqlDataReader reader)
{
var model = new Class1
    {
        Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ID"]),
        Name = reader["Name"].ToString(),
        Class2.
    };
}
```

Why I cannot see the properties of `Class2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dave is correct.  The easiest way to do this with your code is as follows

```
private Class1 GetData(SqlDataReader reader)
{
    var model = new Class1
    {
        Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ID"]),
        Name = reader["Name"].ToString(),
        Params = new Class2()
     };
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to create an `instance` of `Class2`. Your `Params` object of `Class1` needs to be initialized like so:

```
var model = new Class1
{
    Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ID"]),
    Name = reader["Name"].ToString(),
};
model.Params = new Class2();
model.Params.Param1 = "param1";
```

Answer (score 4):

Because when you use `Class2.` you're referencing the class itself, not an instance of the class.

You have to either declare `Class2` as `static` or, in your case, create an instance of it:

```
private Class1 GetData(SqlDataReader reader)
{
    var model = new Class1
    {
        Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ID"]),
        Name = reader["Name"].ToString(),
        Params = new Class2 { Param1 = "foo", Param2 = "bar", Param3 = "other" }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Class1 doesn't have a property called Class2.  You called the property of type "Class2" on Class1, "Params".  So you'd reference it like:

```
private Class1 GetData(SqlDataReader reader)
{
var model = new Class1
    {
        Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ID"]),
        Name = reader["Name"].ToString(),
        Params = new Class2 {
           Param1 = ...
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do sthing like:

```
Class2 = new Class2() { ...}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Params property of Class1 is never assigned to anything and so will always be null.

Also, the property accessor in Class1 is Params, so it should be...

```
private Class1 GetData(SqlDataReader reader)
{
var model = new Class1
    {
        Id = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ID"]),
        Name = reader["Name"].ToString(),
        Params = new Class2() { Param1 = "foo", Param2 = "bar" }
    };
}
```